# Renewenvironment verbatim as lstlisting

Tags: macros, environments

I am using `pandoc` to convert some HTML into LaTeX. `pandoc` converts code (`<pre>`) into `verbatim`, which does not handle line breaks.

As I found on this website, the recommended solution is to switch to `lstlisting`, however I'm not really fan of modifying `pandoc` for that, so I thought I would just *replace* the `verbatim` environment to `lstlisting`, which I fully configured with `lstset` in my document.

I tried, and I failed.

Here is my simple attempt:

```
\renewenvironment{verbatim}{\begin{lstlisting}}{\end{lstlisting}}
```

which produces this error:

> Emergency stop. No legal \end found

Answer (score 5):

You should use `\lstnewenvironment` to define new listings environments. As it is only for new environments you must first undefine verbatim:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
\section{}
\end{verbatim}

\let\verbatim\someundefinedcommand
\lstnewenvironment{verbatim}
{}{}

\begin{verbatim}
\section{}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]